# What is the function of "auch" in "auch so schon genug" – corresponding to "enough as it is" in English?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In conversation, I just said:

> Treib's bloß nicht zu weit, hörst du? Audrey ist **auch so schon genug** um dich besorgt.

- *Don't take it too far, you hear me? Audrey is worried **enough** about you (**even**)  **as it is** without you causing any more trouble.*

To express the idea of "*enough (...) as it is*", I got into the habit of adding "***auch***" to the phrase "***auch*** so schon genug" without actually understanding its precise function.

---

This "*auch*" is, to my mind, placed for further emphasis: "*worried enough about you (**even**)  as it is*". Perhaps in a similar manner to, say:

> I habe den Befehl, niemanden **auch** nur in ihre Nähe zu lassen. -- {***even*** just/only}

---

I'm wondering if I'm on the right track in my interpretation. To say the following in German, should I still include "***auch***" to "***auch*** so schon genug" to make the sentence sound more idiomatic?

- *He's been through **enough** this year (**even**)  **as it is** without any added family drama.*

Comment: Ich würde da "auch ohnehin schon" sagen, aber eine kleine Recherché in Google ergab, dass du es richtig verwendet hast. Glückwunsch  :) NS: du bist wahrscheinlich ja auch ein Muttersprachler...
Im Englischen gibt es halt kein vorangestelltes "auch".
Das mit dem Befehl würde ich als "not even cloze to her" übersetzen.

Comment: Sollte es nicht besser "is already worried enough" - already allerdings für "schon", nicht für "auch" - heißen?

Comment: Liegt die Betonung hier nicht auf "so"? Das erklärt auch die Übersetzung mit "as it is" besser, dann wäre "auch" das Äquivalent zu "already"

Comment: *die ganze woche bleiben, oder auch nur das Wochenende*; *niemanden an Sie heran, auch nur in Ihre Nähe zu lassen*. Somehow I feel there is missing a *gar* and a *je/ja*. *jedoch* ~/~ *jeauch*? Naja, Antworten hast du ja auch so ohne mein Zutun schon schön früh erhalten.

Comment: Ich will's jezuwahr nicht gar zu weit treiben, aber vergleiche doch einmal *so* mit Lat. *se* "without", and *so-ohne* mit Lat. *sine*, Fr. *sans*; En. *sole* "alone, lonely". *so lonely* :'/

Comment: I think the idea of "auch so schon" in the given context is "even without your horryfying / frightening phantasies of all kinds of accidents that could happen." Generally speaking "auch so schon" means "auch ohne", "so" referring back like a sort of global pronoun to the previous (communicative) situation. A previous sentence could have been "noch mehr von deinen Horrorgeschichten können wir / kann Audrey jetzt wirklich nicht gebrauchen."

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if I'm on the right track in my interpretation. To say the following in German, should I still include "auch" to "auch so schon genug" to make the sentence sound more idiomatic?

No, the sentence will not sound any more idiomatic if you add "auch (so)". The adverb just puts more emphasis on it as you already mentioned correctly.

> Er hat dieses Jahr schon genug durchgemacht.
>
> Er hat dieses Jahr auch so schon genug durchgemacht.

Answer (score 0):

> (a) Treibs bloß nicht zu weit, hörst du? Audrey ist **schon genug** um dich besorgt.
>
> (b) Treibs bloß nicht zu weit, hörst du? Audrey ist **so schon genug** um dich besorgt.
>
> (c) Treibs bloß nicht zu weit, hörst du? Audrey ist **auch so schon genug** um dich besorgt.

All options mean the same and reflect the »enough as it is« sufficiently. The emphasis added by (b) and (c) is small.

The second *»auch«* makes only sense with the following *»nur«*, omitting one of the two would change the message. Contrary to the upper *»auch nur«* adds a strong emphasis; your example sentence is a »shorty« of e. g.

> - Ich habe den Befehl, niemanden **auch nur** in ihre Nähe zu lassen, **geschweige denn ganz an sie heran**.
> - Ich habe den Befehl, niemanden **auch nur** in ihre Nähe zu lassen, **geschweige denn, dass ihr jemand ein Geschenk überreicht**.

Answer (score 0):

It is a rather transparent combination of

> reicht so // *as is, like that*
>
> reicht auch // *too, also*
>
> reicht schon // *yet, already, well*

PS: indeed, as another answer says, *auch* is not strictly needed. However *auch schon* is an idiomatic collocation. If some kid says "Das habe ich schon", the eager friend will respond "Ich **auch schon**"; Or maybe *ich auch*, which would appear like an ellipsis (nevermind the lack of an inflected verb in either case).

But the *so* is more interesting, as Latin *se*, "without" compares well. Therefore, "Spass hast du *so schon*, deshalb brauchst du keine Rollschuhe" may have a very different meaning than the other *so*'s; There are so many of them, so that I have to reason further like so: A relation to *sole* "alone, without" is obvious, and a relation to *in this one way and no other* is thinkable.

The importance of *auch* in this collocation, might be the contrast, "you won't get it this way *and* not that way". Indeed, the Dutch cognate *ook* means "and".

It would be skimpy to say that *auch* had just creeped into this phrase by accident, that it was used in redundancy for good measure. We do call phrases fossilized, if the words are not used productively anymore (ie. what is *lieren* in *verlieren*, *forelorn*? Or *verletzen* and what does it have to do with *lust*?). Since many senses of *auch* are used productively, it would be a stretch to call this phrase a fossil, but the gist is that children simply copy the language and rationalize it as they go. What anyone thinks when they say it is of little concern so far, because there may not be one unique answer. So I hold etymology as an important part of interpretation. Although, its etymology eludes me so far. I mean it is well enough a rather volatile idiom, too, like many other conjunctions (cp. Greek *O kei*; Ger *oder auch*?).

*schon* appears like an amalgam of *schön* and En *soon*, maybe with a hint of *shunt*, i.e. "close* ... or rather meaning *early, morning* following a complicated argument I already forgot.